# How is it decided who goes to - Swarga or Pitri Lok?

Tags: death, swarga, pitru

After death people can go to multiple places , main among them are - Pitri Lok , Swarga Lok and Narak Lok .

For Narak it is clear that people who do sins go to Narak.

But I am confused between who goes to - Swarg Lok and who goes to Pitri Lok ?

How is it decided ?

Comment: Pitriloka is situated within Svarga. Pitris enjoy all the facilities afforded by devas except food & water, for which they depend on the offerings of kavya, pinda & tarpana.

Comment: @AnubrataBit So, after dying and going to heaven,**all** people will still need food and water from their descendants ?

Comment: According to Skanda Purana, Nagara Khanda, Chap 216, yes. Shastras that one should perform srāddha & tarpana daily & a special srāddha on the lunar day of one's immmediate ancestors' death anniversary each year. If unable to do so,  then Skanda Purana:6:216 states to perform the same on Manvadi, Yugadi, Samkranti, Vyatipata, Gajacchaya, eclipse & new-moon days throughout the year. If unable in that, perform srāddha & tarpana on Pretapaksha annually. If unable to do that, perform srāddha & tarpana annually on Mahalaya (which co-incidentally happens to fall tommorow) at Gaya.

Comment: This is for those people who have lead a virtous life by performing the Vaidika rites. However, those who have propitiated Bhagavana Shankara, Bhagavana Vishnu & Bhagavati Adyashakti are expected to reach lokas higher than Svarga, where they don't have to experience hunger & thirst.

Comment: Correction: According to the Puranas, those who propitiate Bhagavana Vishnu, Bhagavana Shiva or Bhagavati Adyashakti either reach their respective lokas (Vaikuntha, Shivaloka, Manidvipa) or assume the body of Devas/Gandharvas & reside in Svarga, while those who propitiate the Vaidika deities through Vaidika rites accompany the 7 divine Pitris in Pitriloka situated in the southern part of Svarga, ruled by Yama.

Comment: @AnubrataBit That means ,those who don't have sons can save themselves from hell by  propitiating Bhagavana Vishnu, Bhagavana Shiva or Bhagavati Adyashakti. (Having a son is considered as essential for saving oneself from hell )