# Is it true that those who propitiate Vishnu , Shiva or Bhagwati don't need their descendants to offer Pind-daan to them?

Tags: marriage, pitru, children, heaven

1. Is it true that those who propitiate Vishnu , Shiva or Bhagwati [don't need their descendants to offer Pind-daan to them ?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/52543/how-is-it-decided-who-goes-to-swarga-or-pitri-lok#comment163712_52543)
   Can anyone cite the reference to the scripture where this thing is written ?
2. Do they also get rid of the responsibility of [having a son to get rid of Pitri-Rina](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18580/23709) ?

Is this system of offering [Pind-daan and having a son outdated](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/54028/what-is-pitri-rina-how-to-get-rid-of-it-why-some-people-say-that-having-a-son) as I find many spiritual persons well-versed in scriptures not marrying ?